# How do I remove a word before a dash using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I need to remove all words before the dash at the beginning of each sentence. Some sentences do not have words before dashes and dashes within the long sentence need to stay. Here is an example:

How do I change these strings:

> PARIS — President Nicolas Sarkozy, running from behind for
>   reelection...
>
> GAZA CITY —Cross-border fighting between Gaza and Israel...
>
> CARURU, Colombia — Quite suddenly, the endless green of Amazonian
>   forest...
>
> A year after an earthquake and tsunami devastated Japan's northeastern
>   coast...

Into these strings:

> President Nicolas Sarkozy, running from behind for
>   reelection...
>
> Cross-border fighting between Gaza and Israel...
>
> Quite suddenly, the endless green of Amazonian
>   forest...
>
> A year after an earthquake and tsunami devastated Japan's northeastern
>   coast...

How can I accomplish this with javascript (or php if javascript doesn't allow it)?

Comment: Fair warning - almost all of the answers below will cause problems in a block of text with a) no dateline, and b) a dash somewhere else in the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward regex problem, but geez, it's not as straightforward as all the other answers assume. A few points:

- Regex is the right choice - the `split` and `substr` answers won't deal with the leading space, and can't distinguish between a dateline with a dash at the beginning of a sentence, and a dash in the middle of your text content. Any option you use ought to be able to deal with content like: `"President Nicolas Sarkozy — running from behind for reelection — came to Paris today..."` as well as the options you suggest.
- It's tricky to automatically recognize that my test sentence above doesn't have a dateline. Almost all the answers so far use the single description: `any number of arbitrary characters, followed by a dash`. That's insufficient for a test sentence like the one above.
- You'll get better results by adding a few more rules, like `fewer than X characters, located at the beginning of the string, followed by a dash, optionally followed by an arbitrary number of spaces, followed by a capital letter`. Even this won't work correctly with `"President Sarkozy — Carla Bruni's husband..."`, but you're going to have to assume that this edge case is sufficiently rare to ignore.

All of which gives you a function like this:

```
function removeDateline(str) {
    return str.replace(/^[^—]{3,75}—\s*(?=[A-Z])/, "");
}
```

Breaking it down:

- `^` - must occur at the beginning of the string.
- `[^—]{3,75}` - between 3 and 75 characters other than a dash
- `\s*` - optional spaces
- (?=[A-Z]) - lookahead - the next character must be a capital letter.

Usage:

```
var s = "PARIS — President Nicolas Sarkozy, running from behind for reelection...";
removeDateline(s); // "President Nicolas Sarkozy — running from behind for reelection..."

s = "PARIS — President Nicolas Sarkozy — running from behind for reelection...";
removeDateline(s);  // "President Nicolas Sarkozy — running from behind for reelection..."

s = "CARURU, Colombia — Quite suddenly, the endless green of Amazonian forest...";
removeDateline(s); // "Quite suddenly, the endless green of Amazonian forest..."
```

Comment: hey nrabinowitz, thank you for your reply. what you say sounds great. can you give me a specific example?

Comment: This is really more considered answer, than the other "fast" answers.

Comment: Yep, just hadn't gotten there yet :). See my example and usage above.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to be working. can you try it out with jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Thank you, it works now. However, I have another question: what if there is a word before it that should stay, such as:  
"Now » PARIS — President Nicolas Sarkozy, running from behind for reelection..."
and the "Now »" should stay. How could I best do that?

Comment: If you know that the word will have `»` after it, then you can add it to the regex pretty easily, but you'll have to change the replacement to include it: `str.replace(/^([^—»]+» )?[^—]{3,75}—[\s]*(?=[A-Z])/, "$1");`

Answer (score 0):

If each sentence can be separated from the others you can use a regexp. Like this example:

```
var s = "PARIS — President Nicolas Sarkozy, running from behind for reelection..."
function removeWord(str)
{
    return str.replace(/^[^—]+—[\s]*/, "");
}
alert(removeWord(s));
```

​

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
$x = "PARIS — President Nicolas Sarkozy, running from behind for reelection...";
$var = substr($x, strpos($x, "—"));
```

Comment: your answer should include explanation and background information on the solution you provide

Answer (score 0):

In the most basic example:

```
var str = "PARIS - President Nicolas Sarkozy, running from behind for reelection.";
alert(str.split('-')[1]);​ // outputs: President Nicolas Sarkozy, running from behind for reelection.
```

Based on your actual document structure there could be ways to loop through the content to speed this type of operation up.